# Mailpoet cause issue because of WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpml

We have activate WPML multilingual CMS plugin "http://wpml.org/" in our website "http://www.chabadpbrome.com/" and its work good but there is one conflicting issue with mailpoet plugin "https://wordpress.org/plugins/wysija-newsletters/" (We have purchased premium version of Mailpoet).

If we deactivate the WPML multilingual CMS plugin, then Mailpoet work properly.

The problem is we cannot scroll for more post. When we try to create new newsletter in Mailpoet from Mailpoet > newsletter > Create a new email > after that there is visual dashboard for creating mail newsletter.

Here we attached screencasts for better understanding:

1. http://screencast.com/t/9EIohbKm0
2. http://screencast.com/t/cy8y7cEAaFd

Comment: This problem are solved..

This is problem is with my theme JS conflict and other is mail poet don't work with HTTPS as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This problem are solved..

This is problem is with my theme JS conflict and other is mail poet don't work with HTTPS as it should.